# How to get x-coordinate of a touch event point relative to the target element?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

So I have an image that looks like this:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("bt");
elem.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);

function handleStart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var touch = e.targetTouches[0];
  X = touch.pageX;
  Y = touch.pageY;
  return [X, Y];
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/sections-3.jpg" id="bt" width="900" height="600">
```

What I want to do, is get the x- and y-coordinates of a touch event relative to the image itself.

Comment: What do you mean by " get the x and y coordinates of a touch event relative to the image"

Comment: What i mean is in top of the image y = 0 and in the left x =0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve that easily using `Jquery`.In my code I am showing using `click` event since i am using desktop but you can replace click by touch event.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/7m9179d0/)

Here is the code:

```js
$('.clickable').bind('click', function(ev) {
  var $div = $(ev.target);
  var $display = $div.find('.display');

  var offset = $div.offset();
  var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
  var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;

  $display.text('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
});
```

```css
.clickable {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #eee;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.display {
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clickable'>
  <span class='display'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set image position to absolute and set its start coordinates (here I set it to top left corner)

```
#bt{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
```

now touch coordinates are image pixel coordinates. You may want to take to account available page size and window size and scale.

Also you can take elements coordinates by

```
var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
```

Then you can use those values as `touch.x - rect.left`  etc.

Comment: But what if i have a header for example in top of the page, is this the only way ?